# Extracting text between two strings using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a value corresponding to value in the below dataset using regex. Given below is how my data looks like:

```
[{'self': 'text123', 'value': 'Keyword 1', 'id': '201'},
 {'self': 'text234', 'value': 'Keyword 2', 'id': '202'}, 
 {'self': 'text456', 'value': 'Keyword 3', 'id': '203'}, 
 {'self': 'text789', 'value': 'Keywork 4', 'id': '204'}]
```

This is what I tried:

```
re.findall(r'value (.*?) id', data)
```

The above code throws an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Expected output:

```
Keyword 1, Keyword 2, Keyword 3, Keyword 4
```

Comment: @SaiSreenivas, this is a column in my Dataframe and the `dtype` of this column is `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably work better if done with a json deserializer but if you really want to use a regex I tried this one and it worked. It is super clunky but it works.

```
\'value\': '(.*?)', \'id\'
```

Full code:

```
import re

data = "[{'self': 'text123', 'value': 'Keyword 1', 'id': '201'}, \
 {'self': 'text234', 'value': 'Keyword 2', 'id': '202'}, \
 {'self': 'text456', 'value': 'Keyword 3', 'id': '203'}, \
 {'self': 'text789', 'value': 'Keywork 4', 'id': '204'}]"

print(re.findall(r"\'value\': '(.*?)', \'id\'", data))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have dictionaries stored in a column as a string, you still could access their values without regex:

```py
def extract_keyword(s):
    result = []
    for d in eval(s):
        result.append(d["value"])
    return ", ".join(result)


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col": ["""[{'self': 'text123', 'value': 'Keyword 1', 'id': '201'},
 {'self': 'text234', 'value': 'Keyword 2', 'id': '202'}, 
 {'self': 'text456', 'value': 'Keyword 3', 'id': '203'}, 
 {'self': 'text789', 'value': 'Keywork 4', 'id': '204'}]"""]
})


df["col"].apply(extract_keyword)
```

```
0    Keyword 1, Keyword 2, Keyword 3, Keywork 4
Name: col, dtype: object
```